# How to refactor EF data access code to avoid context issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to get and update EF object but I am getting error:

> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by
>   multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

I understand what is the issue.
But how to properly write data access methods to avoid issues like this?

```
var store = (new StoresRepository(connectionString)).GetStore(1);
// Change store object
(new StoresRepository(connectionString)).Update(store);
```

Data access code:

```
public class StoresRepository
    {
        AppDbContext context;

        public StoresRepository(string connectionString)
        {
            context = new AppDbContext(connectionString);
        }

        public Store GetStore(int storeId)
        {
            var store = context.Stores.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.StoreId == storeId);

            return store;
        }
        public void Update(Store store)
        {
            context.Stores.Attach(store);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: You should have single context/repository objects _per request_. Every time a user requests a page, initialize each of those objects and keep them for the life of the request. You can use the `Application_BeginRequest` method in `global.asax` to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Repository object instead of creating new ones every time.

```
var repo = new StoresRepository(connectionString);

var store = repo.GetStore(1);

repo.Update(store);
```